# could not convert ... from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I'm trying to fix a specific failure now for about two hours and I'm done with my knowledge. Any Ideas?

### The Failure:

```
could not convert '{{TEST1, (& ffm::cond_test1)}, {TEST2, (& ffm::cond_test2)}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::map<ffm::conditions, bool (*)()>'
```

### The code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

namespace ffm {
    typedef bool (*condFunction)();

    enum conditions {
        TEST1 = 0,
        TEST2
    };

    bool cond_test1();
    bool cond_test2();
}

using namespace ffm;

bool cond_test1()
{
    std::cout << "cond_test1 is always TRUE" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool cond_test2()
{
    std::cout << "cond_test2 is always FALSE" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::map<conditions, condFunction> condFuncMap = { 
        {conditions::TEST1, &cond_test1}, 
        {conditions::TEST2, &cond_test2} };

}
```

I'm using gcc4.8.4

Comment: A using directive doesn't mean everything that follows is added as member of that namespace, it just brings the names within that namespace into scope. Define your functions as `bool ffm::cond_test1() { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your functions as being preceded with `ffm::`. This is because your `using` directive simply means that `cond_test1`/`cond_test2` can be called without using `ffm::`. If you do not put `ffm::` before the proper definitions, they will be like more overloads of the function (`::cond_test1`, `::cond_test2`), and the compiler will not be able to tell which overload you want `ffm::cond_test1` or `::cond_test1` as the namespace does not need naming)

```
    bool ffm::cond_test1()
    {
        std::cout << "cond_test1 is always TRUE" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    bool ffm::cond_test2()
    {
        std::cout << "cond_test2 is always FALSE" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
```